# How can I remove observations from a data frame conditionally without losing NA values in R?

Tags: r, subset, na, missing-data

In the data frame there is a variable called `YOB`. As you can see, there are 333 `NA` values.

```
> summary(train$YOB)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
   1880    1970    1983    1980    1993    2039     333
```

---

I identified some outliers and want to get rid of them. Anything less than 1900 and greater than 2003 shall be removed. I tried to do this by indexing.

```
train = train[which(train$YOB >= 1900 & train$YOB <= 2003),]
```

---

Unfortunately observations whose `YOB` variable were `NA` are also removed.

```
> summary(train$YOB)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1900    1970    1983    1980    1993    2003
```

---

On a side note, I face the same problem when using `subset` command.

```
> train = subset(train, YOB >= 1900 & YOB <= 2003)
> summary(train$YOB)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1900    1970    1983    1980    1993    2003
```

---

I have also tried to use this condition in both attempts, but with no success, e.g.

```
> train = train[which(!is.na(train$YOB) & train$YOB >= 1900 & train$YOB <= 2003),]
> summary(train$YOB)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1900    1970    1983    1980    1993    2003
```

---

**I would like to keep the observations that have `NA` in the `YOB` variable and only remove those that are numeric. The idea is in a second step to impute missing values.**

Comment: That works, thanks @akrun - If someone can explain the difference, I'd be happy to accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `which` will give the numeric index and skip all those NA rows.  To avoid that, use the logical index without wrapping with `which`.  The index will be NA in that way and that row will remain as NA even if there are other values that are non-NA.

```
res1 <- train[train$YOB >= 1900 & train$YOB <= 2003,]
res1[is.na(res1$YOB),]
#   YOB col2
#NA  NA   NA
```

The correct way would be to have another condition with `is.na`

```
res2 <- train[is.na(train$YOB)| (train$YOB >= 1900 & train$YOB <= 2003),]
res2[is.na(res2$YOB),]
#   YOB      col2
#42  NA 0.2258094
```

---

Using a simple example

```
set.seed(25)
d1 <- data.frame(v1 = c(NA, 1, 5), v2 = rnorm(3))
d1$v1 >1
#[1]    NA FALSE  TRUE
```

Here, the `NA` value remains as such.  If we use `which`

```
which(d1$v1 >1)
#[1] 3
```

we get only the index of the TRUE values.  According to OP, both the NA and the rows that satisfy the logical condition should return.  In that case,

```
d1[is.na(d1$v1)|d1$v1 > 1,]
# v1         v2
#1 NA -0.2118336
#3  5 -1.1533076
```

#### data

```
set.seed(29)
train <- data.frame(YOB = sample(c(NA, 1850:2015), 100, replace=TRUE), 
           col2 = rnorm(100))
```

Comment: Excellent. You even answered a subsequent question I had in mind. Thank you for your help.